# App Startup in OSX with Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, objective-c, macos, monomac, xamarin.mac

How would one run an app at startup (user login) with Xamarin.Mac?

So far I have come across a few solutions, of which I have run in to some difficulties and want to gauge which is best before proceeding.

**Service Management Framework**

Using [this](http://oss.linn.co.uk/repos/Public/Songbox/Linn/Songbox/MacOsX/AppDelegate.cs) example, I was able to create a small class wrapping the framework. See [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/DanubeRS/7a546375503f64195103). I then embedded as a public read only singleton in the app delegate. However, when clicking the bound "Launch on Startup" button, the logs reveal the following message;

```
 19/10/2015 3:53:31.954 PM My Application[#####]: Could not enable login item: My.App: 3: No such process
```

Despite using the `CFBundleIdentifier` in the value, I can't seem to get it to function.

**`Launchd` Property List**

Another option I discovered was creating a `.plist` file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` with a structure not unlike [this example](https://gist.github.com/DanubeRS/d8d31b9445d950944498) for LastPass. However, this seems static, and would break if the `.app` was not stored in a common location.

As it stands, I would prefer using the Service Management Framework wrapper as it abstracts a little more, but I would like to see if any other community members have come across, and conquered the issue.

Cheers

Comment: Did you manage to fix this one?

Comment: I did, however I no longer have immediate access to the source for this as I have since left the project I was working on.

IIRC however, I ended up using the LaunchAgents method as it seemed to be the most commonly used. Hope this helps, and if you are going to use the same approach, [this](http://launchd.info/) is a stellar resource.